# Android Application with Raspberry Pi communication

Tags: android, websocket, raspberry-pi

I am currently developing on a project which utilises **3 Raspberry Pi and an Android Application**.

**1 of the RPI** is working as the **Access Point** (2 RPI and Android to be connected to this AP) - communication between the devices are done through WiFi.

While the other **2 of the RPI are installed with sensors to provide data to the Android Application.**

As of now, I am able to send data from the Android Application to the RPI using web sockets where my RPI will use a python script to listen to a socket for the incoming data from the Android Application.

However, this is rightly the opposite of what I intend to do as I am trying to make the Android Application be the listener of the data that will be incoming from the 2 RPI installed with sensors.

Is it viable for me to look further into web socket for this solution (as I am clearly a beginner in this), or is there a better way for me to achieve this knowing that the amount of RPI with sensors can increase in due time?

Thanks!

Comment: `As of now, I am able to send data from the Android Application to the RPI`. Uncomplete info. To which of the three?

Comment: What is the problem to program a socket server for Android to which client apps on the raspis can connect? You do not need websockets either.

Comment: @greenapps,  I didn't specify to which RPI as the socket script can be run on any 
of the 3 RPIs. I think this is probably not the best way by any means in suitability to my project however i'm going to proceed to try the MQTT protocol as suggested by the following answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using MQTT protocol. MQTT protocol is a publish-subscriber-based messaging protocol and is built on top of TCP/IP protocol.
In use-cases where you need a small code foot print and data transfer size should be small, it's recommended. You can read more about it [here](http://mqtt.org/).

In a data communication scheme based on mqtt, you need one mqtt broker - it can be the raspberry pi that is access point, and all other raspberry pis and your android device can connect send and receive data using this broker.

In MQTT you can define a **topic**. Some devices can **subscribe** to a topic and when some other devices **publish** some data on that topic, subscribers receive the data. 
Read more about publish-subscriber method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

There are libraries both for android and python to use MQTT messaging protocol. Check out these for example:

[paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) for python

[paho.mqtt.android](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android) for android

Sample codes are available in the links I provided above.

Comment: Nice answer. Nice info. I should try that one day.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for the excellent information! I will go ahead and try the following protocol to see if it works out for me.